# smarty string replace two times in a row

Tags: string, replace, smarty, prestashop

Good day all.
I've a little issue about creating https links and the only entry point I got is smarty, so my idea was to simply search and replace the string `http` with `https`, but, just to be sure, I'd like to convert also the string `httpss`into `https` to handle those links already served as https.

Actually I'm doing this:

```
{$link->getCategoryLink($smarty.get.id_category, null, $lang.id_lang,null,null )|replace:"http":"https"}
```

is there a way to add another string replace in the same row?
I mean something like:

```
{($link->getCategoryLink($smarty.get.id_category, null, $lang.id_lang,null,null )|replace:"http":"https")|replace:"httpss":"https"}
```

I'm using smarty only twice a year, so I'm not so expert there and I don't want to add complexity (that I'll not be able to read the next year) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better options in Smarty (`regex_replace` for example), but for a more correct replacement, couldn't you just replace the whole protocol?

```
{$link->getCategoryLink($smarty.get.id_category, null, $lang.id_lang,null,null )|replace:"http://":"https://"}
```

That way you can be sure it won't replace a part of the link containing the word `http` (not in the protocol), and only `http://` links will be replaced